# Removing spacing between adjacent sections and subsections (titlesec)

Tags: spacing, titlesec, programming, etoolbox

I am building out sections and subsections. The beforesep on subsections is desirable generally, but not if a subsection is invoked directly following a section. Is there any way to take care of this?

I have tried to do this using `\pretocmd` from etoolbox, but unfortunately not working as desired. Please see below for MWE. Desired outcome is no space between Section 1 and Subsection 1, but standard space then between "Some text here (subsection 1)." and Subsection 2:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

% Define a toggle to check if a section was just created
\newtoggle{aftersection}

% Formatting the section titles
\titleformat{\section}
  {\Large\bfseries}
  {\thesection}
  {1em}
  {\toggletrue{aftersection}} % Set the toggle to true after creating a section

% Formatting the subsection titles
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\large\bfseries}
  {\thesubsection}
  {1em}
  {}

% Adjusting the space before and after section titles
\titlespacing{\section}
  {0pt} % left
  {2ex} % beforesep
  {1ex} % aftersep

% Adjusting the space before and after subsection titles
\titlespacing{\subsection}
  {0pt} % left
  {0pt} % beforesep (set to 0pt initially)
  {0.5ex} % aftersep

% Update the spacing before subsections depending on the toggle
\pretocmd{\subsection}{%
  \iftoggle{aftersection}{
    \vspace{-2cm} % Remove the space before the subsection
    \togglefalse{aftersection} % Reset the toggle
  }{
    \vspace{2cm} % Add the space before the subsection
  }
}{\typeout{Success}}{\typeout{Failed to patch \string\subsection}}

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}

\subsection{Subsection 1}
Some text here.

\subsection{Subsection 2}
Some more text here.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out that if spacing is purely configured within titlespacing it respect subsequent sections and does not add more spacing